# Magento 2 : get custom attribute value display blank

Tags: magento2, catalog, eav-attributes

In Magento2 , I need to get eav attribute value in category data. I used this below code. But, it's not working.

```
/** \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory**/
$category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load(12); //12 is category id
$category->getData('attribute-code');
```

This attribute code value available in `catalog_category_entity_varchar` table.

**M1 Array :**

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 12
    [entity_type_id] => 3
    [attribute_set_id] => 3
    [parent_id] => 3
    [created_at] => 2014-04-29T00:25:55+02:00
    [updated_at] => 2017-09-20 11:40:47
    [path] => 1/2/3/12
    [position] => 2
    [level] => 3
    [children_count] => 0
    [request_path] => requestpath
    [is_active] => 1
    [name] => name
    [url_key] => url_key
    [is_anchor] => 0
    [meta_title] => 
    [display_mode] => PRODUCTS
    [custom_design] => 
    [page_layout] => one_column
    [url_path] => url
    [style] => 
    [faq_list_position] => 1
    [include_in_menu] => 1
    [landing_page] => 
    [custom_use_parent_settings] => 0
    [custom_apply_to_products] => 0
    [description] => 
    [meta_keywords] => meta
    [meta_description] => meta1
    [custom_layout_update] => 
    [available_sort_by] => Array
        (
            [0] => position
        )

    [custom_design_from] => 
    [custom_design_to] => 
    [filter_price_range] => 
)
```

**M2 Array :**

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 12
    [attribute_set_id] => 46
    [parent_id] => 3
    [created_at] => 2014-04-28 22:25:55
    [updated_at] => 2019-04-05 10:23:19
    [path] => 1/2/3/12
    [position] => 2
    [level] => 3
    [children_count] => 0
    [name] => name
    [url_key] => urlkey
    [image] => 
    [meta_title] => title
    [display_mode] => PRODUCTS
    [url_path] => urlpath
    [custom_design] => 
    [page_layout] => 1column
    [is_active] => 1
    [include_in_menu] => 1
    [landing_page] => 
    [is_anchor] => 0
    [custom_use_parent_settings] => 0
    [custom_apply_to_products] => 0
    [description] => 
    [meta_keywords] => meta
    [meta_description] => meta1
    [custom_layout_update] => 
    [available_sort_by] => Array
        (
            [0] => position
        )

    [custom_design_from] => 
    [custom_design_to] => 
)
```

How i get value ?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: why you do not extension attribute?

Comment: Can you please elobarate more?

Comment: seems `Magento\Catalog\Model\CatalogFactory` wrong ` it should be `Magento\Catalog\Model\CatagoryFactory`

Comment: Sorry. It's my mistake. It's typo

Comment: In v2.3.1, this value not display. I migrate data from 1.9.2.1 to 2.3.1

Comment: @AmitBera Can you please tell me why it's not working?

Comment: Use `_` and not `-` in your attribute code

Comment: Have you add a custom field (attribute ) in category?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get data like this,

```
$category->getData('attribute_code');

 OR

$category->getAttributeCode();
```

Comment: Not working,...

Comment: Is the attributed created in eav_attribute table?

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: If still not work run reindex. @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd.

Comment: Try this
$atts= $category->getAttributes();
var_dump($atts);

Comment: @AveshNaik It returns object.

Comment: Are there repo interface for categories? For customer i had same kind of problem, solved using repo interface.

Comment: Can you please update answer?

Answer (score 0):

As this attribute are not magento default attribute and there are not setter and getter method are not defined at the data interface  `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface` So, `$category->getData('attribute-code');` you cannot get this attribute value.

If you want then you have to use `$category->getCustomAttribute($attributeCode)`

**Like:**

```
    $category = $this->categoryFactory->create();
    $category->load(12);
    $customAttributeValue = $category->getCustomAttribute($attributeCode);
   if(null !== $customAttributeValue){
       $myAttributeValue = $customAttributeValue->getValue();
   }
```

I do not support or use  this type of work.**If will be better to use   [Extension attribute](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html)** using  Service contact class `Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface`

*BUT, Extension attribute is not working for Category entity for the blog https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10847,So you can get `getCustomAttribute` or `getCustomAttributes()`*

***Forgetting the data, you can use service contact interface***

```
$storeId = 1;
try{
    /// $this->categoryRepository is instean of Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface
   $category = $this->categoryRepository->get(12, $storeId);
   $customAttributeValue = $category->getCustomAttribute($attributeCode);
   if (null !== $customAttributeValue) {
       $myAttributeValue = $customAttributeValue->getValue();
   }           
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $ex) {

}
```

Comment: what should i need to extend? Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface or Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory ?

Comment: Still, it's return blank. Can you please help me?

Comment: No. It's not working. Is it any migrate issue?

Comment: The extension attribute is not working on Magento category entity SEE. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10847 .It is bad for us. You have to

Comment: You can check M1 and M2 array. There are entity_type_id is missing in M2 array. That's why i can't get attribute value or?

Comment: already explain u `As this attribute are not magento default attribute and there are not setter and getter method are not defined at the data interface  Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface `

Answer (score 0):

In front, You can get the value of Category attribute by load category object and call the function like below.

```
$getCategory = CATEGORY_OBJECT;
echo $getCategory->getCustomCategoryField();
```

Take reference from below link.

- [Add category attribute Programmatically in Magento 2.](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/add-category-attribute-programmatically-in-magento-2/)
- [How to get Category collection by Category id in magento 2?](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-get-category-collection-by-category-id-in-magento-2/)

I hope it helps!

Comment: This is not working. You can check M1 and M2 array. There are entity_type_id is missing in M2 array. That's why i can't get attribute value or?